# How to fix Haskell "error: [-Wincomplete-patterns, -Werror=incomplete-patterns]"

Tags: function, haskell, incomplete-type

Can some one tell me, why i am getting the following error:

```
error: [-Wincomplete-patterns, -Werror=incomplete-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In a case alternative: Patterns not matched: []
   |
54 |   case list of
   |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^...
```

Thats my test:

```
testMinBy :: Test
testMinBy = TestCase $ do
  assertEqual "test1" (minBy (\x -> -x) [1,2,3,4,5]) 5
  assertEqual "test2" (minBy length ["a", "abcd", "xx"]) "a"
```

```
minBy :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> a
minBy measure list =
  case list of
    (x:y:xs) -> minBy measure (if measure x > measure y then y:xs else x:xs)
    [x] -> x
```

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern does not matches with the empty list. Indeed, that is what the error is saying. You can match the empty list, for example with:

```
minBy :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> a
minBy measure list =
  case list of
    (x:y:xs) -> minBy measure (if measure x > measure y then y:xs else x:xs)
    [x] -> x
    [] -> error "Empty list"
```

Your function however is not very efficient: it will recalculate `measure` multiple times if an item is the current minimum, and will also pack and unpack lists. You can work with an accumulator here, like:

```
minBy :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> a
minBy _ [] = error "Empty list"
minBy f (x:xs) = go xs x (f x)
  where go [] y _ = y
        go (y₁:ys) y₀ fy₀
          | fy₁ < fy₀ = go ys y₁ fy₁
          | otherwise = go ys y₀ fy₀
          where fy₁ = f y₁
```

This means it only once has to check for an empty list, and then knows for sure that this is a non-empty list if it enumerates. It also will determine the `f` of each item exactly once, and uses accumulators to avoid packing and unpacking a "cons".